# Node Angularjs on page load not loading data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

On login I am redirecting to a different page, there is  where the partial page is loaded from the Angularjs route. So on click of any anchor tag respective partial view is loaded.

I have a problem here...on login I am having a res.render(pagenname,{data:data1, data2:data4}). Here data2 and data4 is coming from the database. This data2 and data4 are to be loaded in partial page. I have assigned #{data} on partial page but I dont see the data coming there.

What could the issue be.

Comment: Didn't you post a similar qustion like an hour ago?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expressjs res.render not rendering values in angularjs partials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201441/expressjs-res-render-not-rendering-values-in-angularjs-partials)

Comment: So `!{}` didn't work?

Comment: no..I am trying all possible things!!

Comment: Does Jade throw an error or is it actually rendering

Comment: its rendering..but without data

Comment: Strange it should throw an error if it can't see the data. So what appears instead of the data?

Comment: Last Time Sheet was at #{DateTime} and was #{timesheet} this is what I get when the partial is loaded

Comment: Yea so I don't think Jade is actually interpreting those as variables. If it did it would throw an error.

Comment: Did you add a dot after your script tag? `script(type="text/javascript").`

Comment: Oh wait you're outputting them as text or as a JS variable?

Comment: res.render('employelogin/employlogin', { title: 'Sheet| Employee',userName: req.session.nameName,DateTime:resultDate,timesheet:timeSheet});

Comment: Yea it's probably something wrong with your Jade syntax. Try creating variables inside your template and see if you can display those the same way.

Comment: {"type": "text", "name": "Bob"} input(type=type, value='Hello #{name}')
This is what I tried on jaded and nops this dosen work!!

Comment: Well if you can't do something that simple you need to work on your Jade syntax. Check out last example http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/

Comment: This is the code
- var user = { name: 'John' }
if user
  Welcome, #{user.name}
THis is nor rendering

Comment: maybe update your version of Jade, I don't know.

Comment: lol yea there's your problem

Comment: what??????????????????

Comment: Current Jade version is 1.3.0

Comment: 0.0.1 is dinosaur stuff.

Comment: nops...no luck...its still the same now jade is 1.3.0 on package.json did a npm update --save

Comment: You sure? Seems strange that you can't do something from the tutorial and it's not even throwing an error. AFAIK 0.0.1 didn't have variables, 1.3.0 throws an error if you call a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Nothing that I see..in terms of error!!

Comment: Yea actually nvm about the error part, I just tried it and I was wrong, it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Still though if you can't reproduce the example in the tutorial something is wrong.

Comment: When the page loads the example works...if its from partial page daammmm it...it dosent!!

Answer (score 0):

Run this to upgrade jade

`npm up jade`